# I have a SQL Stored procedure in Oracle database with parameter as timestamp. How to call the procedure

Tags: java, oracle

The Oracle Stored procedure looks like below...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procedure1 (p_date IN TIMESTAMP) 
IS
BEGIN
...
END;
/
```

when trying to execute with below

```
EXEC procedure1 ( to_timestamp( '06/30/2020', 'MM/DD/YYYY' ));
```

But getting below error

> The input data to be converted using a date format model was
> incorrect.  The input data did not contain a number where a number was
> required by the format model

Comment: `to_timestamp( '06/30/2020', 'MM/DD/YYYY' )` is correct format for timestamp. It should not throw any error because of this conversion.

Comment: [edit] your question and post the entire text of the Oracle error you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use timestamp literals: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-192417E8-A79D-4A1D-9879-68272D925707

For example

```
EXEC procedure1 ( timestamp'2019-12-31 01:23:59');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the fulltime stamp in the below format YYYYMMDDHHMISS and convert it into timestamp in the procedure.